# How to, with script, export and import tables from one database to another.

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've been trying to figure out how to export and import tables from my database and havent made much success so far. 
There is a way you can do this by simply saving the database tables in a file and then importing it, this would work but i'm more interested of making a program that will makes a backup of my database on a regular basis instead of me doing the steps everyday.

So my question is: 
is there something i can write in SQL command that will export/import several tables from one database to another?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `mysql`, `mysqldump` and a cronjob (walk into a bar?)

Comment: @JonStirling and `cronjob` already has 3 drinks waiting for them?

Comment: How are you currently 'simply' saving the database tables to a file?